# How to prove |– (U → V ) → ((¬U → V ) → V)? Or how to deduce V from (U → V ), (¬U→V) using Deduction theorem?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is what I need to ultimately prove: |– (U → V ) → ((¬U → V ) → V)

We have these axioms and modus ponens:

Axiom 1 is: P→(Q→P)

Axiom 2 is: (P→(Q→R))→((P→Q)→(P→R))

Axiom 3 is: (¬Q→¬P)→ (P→Q)

Modus ponens is: from P and P→Q infer Q

A proof in this manner means a sequence of lines where each line is an axiom, or a formula from your "base" set ({α,¬α} below), or an inference (using modus ponens), with the last line being the formula being proved.

I used the deduction theorem to say that a finding a proof from the empty set of that formula is equivalent to finding a proof:

(U → V ), (¬U→V) |– V

Using these axioms and modus penons I want to infer V from (U → V ), (¬U→V)

I'm a bit stuck here. Any help please?

Comment: Contrapositive on $U \rightarrow V$ is $\neg V \rightarrow \neg U$. Chaining the two, $\neg V \rightarrow \neg U \rightarrow V$. So if $V$ were false, it would also be true, and we'd have a contradiction, so $V$ must be true?

Comment: But sadly for that we must have ¬V as a hypothesis, and we only have  (¬V→¬U) as a hypothesis ( which we infered from (U→V)→(¬V→¬U) )

Comment: Also, you do not wish to derive $\neg V$ at all.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What should I derive then?

Comment: Any help, please?:( I don't know how to bump the question

Comment: https://incredible.pm/ uses this system, and the approach it uses (which I've worked through so I know it works - though using the Deduction Theorem would be much easier than what you need to do at that site) uses as intermediate steps: $\lnot A\rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$; $(\lnot A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A$; $A\leftrightarrow\lnot\lnot A$; $(B\rightarrow A)\rightarrow(\lnot A\rightarrow \lnot B)$.

Comment: Although: should axiom 3 actually be $(\lnot Q\rightarrow\lnot P)\rightarrow(P\rightarrow Q)$?  For instance, all three axioms as listed are valid in intuitionistic propositional logic, whereas the conclusion is not.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you for your response! I wrote axiom 3 as it is written in our textbook: (U → V ) → (¬V →¬U ). I'm a bit confused too

Comment: @DanielSchepler I found out that we can change the axioms. So I can write axiom 3 as (¬Q→¬P)→ (P→Q). Do you know how I could deduce V now? I'm not sure from where that site begins with ¬A→(A→B)

Comment: Rather than trying to guess or figure out a proof for a propositional expression, you should study the completeness proof of propositional logic and use that to systematically prove any true expression.

Comment: A proof can be found here (scroll down a little bit) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example

Answer (score 1):

The proof that I know of is fairly tricky, and consists on bootstrapping up several results from axiom 3 in turn, using the Deduction Theorem.

**Lemma schema 1:** $\vdash \lnot A\rightarrow(A \rightarrow B)$.

*Proof*: By the Deduction Theorem, it suffices to show $\lnot A \vdash A \rightarrow B$.  Then, using axiom 3 and a modus ponens, we reduce to showing that $\lnot A \vdash \lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$.  This is now easy. $\square$

**Lemma schema 2:** $\vdash (\lnot A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A$.

*Proof*: By the Deduction Theorem, it suffices to show that $\lnot A\rightarrow A\vdash A$.  Now, in general, for any propositional formula $P$, we have that $\lnot A\rightarrow A, \lnot A \vdash P$ through concluding $A$ as well, and then applying lemma schema 1.  But then, by the Deduction Theorem, we conclude that $\lnot A\rightarrow A \vdash \lnot A \rightarrow P$.  In particular, $\lnot A\rightarrow A \vdash \lnot A \rightarrow \lnot(\lnot A \rightarrow A)$; and now, combining this fact with axiom 3 and an application of modus ponens, we then see that $\lnot A\rightarrow A \vdash (\lnot A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A$.  Since $\lnot A\rightarrow A \vdash \lnot A\rightarrow A$ also, a modus ponens gives the required conclusion $\lnot A \rightarrow A \vdash A$. $\square$

**Lemma schema 3:** $\vdash \lnot\lnot A \rightarrow A$.

*Proof:* By the Deduction Theorem, it suffices to show that $\lnot\lnot A \vdash A$.  Now, $\lnot\lnot A \vdash \lnot A\rightarrow A$ using lemma schema 1 and a modus ponens.  Now, from lemma schema 2 (and extension of context) we also have $\lnot\lnot A \vdash (\lnot A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A$, and a modus ponens gives the desired conclusino $\lnot\lnot A \vdash A$. $\square$

**Lemma schema 4:** $\vdash A \rightarrow \lnot\lnot A$.

*Proof:* Using axiom 3 and a modus ponens, it suffices to show $\vdash \lnot\lnot\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot A$.  This is then a specialization of lemma schema 3. $\square$

**Lemma schema 5:** $\vdash (A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(\lnot B\rightarrow \lnot A)$.

*Proof:* By the Deduction Theorem, it suffices to show $A\rightarrow B \vdash \lnot B\rightarrow \lnot A$.  Using axiom 3 and a modus ponens, we reduce to showing $A \rightarrow B \vdash \lnot\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot\lnot B$.  By another application of the Deduction Theorem, it suffices to show $A\rightarrow B, \lnot\lnot A \vdash \lnot\lnot B$.  But then, lemma schema 3 and a modus ponens gives $A \rightarrow B, \lnot\lnot A \vdash A$; a modus ponens gives $A \rightarrow B, \lnot \lnot A \vdash B$; and finally, lemma schema 4 and a modus ponens gives from this that $A\rightarrow B, \lnot\lnot A \vdash \lnot\lnot B$. $\square$

**Final result:** $\vdash (U\rightarrow V) \rightarrow [(\lnot U\rightarrow V)\rightarrow V]$.

*Proof:* By two applications of the Deduction Theorem, it suffices to show $U\rightarrow V, \lnot U\rightarrow V \vdash V$.  But by lemma schema 5, $U\rightarrow V, \lnot U\rightarrow V \vdash \lnot V\rightarrow \lnot U$; and combining with the assumption $\lnot U \rightarrow V$, an easy argument gives $\lnot V\rightarrow V$.  But now by lemma schema 2, $U\rightarrow V, \lnot U\rightarrow V \vdash (\lnot V\rightarrow V)\rightarrow V$ also; and a final modus ponens gives what we wanted. $\square$